# WPF style problem

Tags: wpf, styles

I am actually using windows classic style in my applications by using the following declaration

`<ResourceDictionary Source="/PresentationFramework.Classic;V3.0.0.0;31bf3856ad364e35;component/themes/classic.xaml" />`

But whenever i declare a style to any of my controls say to set the font size and font family the appearance of the control also changes to suit the system theme and thus the control loses the classic appearance.
What could be happening?
I tried using

`<Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}" >`

to see if this helps me in getting back the classic theme. But it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: It works for me. Can you give a full example of one of your styles?

Comment: <pre><Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}" >
        <Setter Property="FontFamily">
            <Setter.Value>
                <local:Font Key="ButtonText" Converter="{StaticResource FontConverter}" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="13.33" />
    </Style><code>

Comment: Can you try setting the FontFamily inline with a valid value like <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Tahoma"></Setter>. If this works i am guessing that there is an error with your declaration of font family value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try if this works

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/PresentationFramework.Classic;V3.0.0.0;31bf3856ad364e35;component/themes/classic.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <Style x:Key="ExtendedButtonStyle" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                </Style>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Button Content="click" Height="30" Width="100" Style="{StaticResource ExtendedButtonStyle}"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: This seems to be working. Can you please tell me what's happening? @biju